# Product Same Output XML using XSLT for different input XML formats

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The input XML may be in one of these forms:

Example 1:

```
<studentRequest>
  <student> 
      <name>name</name>  
      <address>      
         <state>stateName</state>
         <city>cityName</city>
         <pin>123456</pin>
      </address>
       <no>123</no> 
    </student>
</studentRequest>
```

Example 2

```
<studentRequest>
  <student>         
      <address>
         <city>cityName</city>
         <pin>123456</pin>
         <state>stateName</state>
      </address>
      <name>name</name>
      <no>123</no>
</student>
</studentRequest>
```

Desired output:

```
<studentRequest>
    <student>
      <address>
         <city>cityName</city>
         <pin>123456</pin>
         <state>stateName</state>
      </address>
      <name>name</name>
      <no>123</no>
    </student>
</studentRequest>
```

I wrote XSLT as follows

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <studentRequest>
       <xsl:if test="student">
         <xsl:element name="student">
           <xsl:if test="student/name">
            <xsl:element name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="student/name"/>
            </xsl:element>
           </xsl:if>
           <xsl:if test="student/no">
            <xsl:element name="no">
                <xsl:value-of select="student/no"/>
            </xsl:element>
           </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="student/address">
            <xsl:element name="address">
                ............
                ...............
            </xsl:element>
           </xsl:if>
           </xsl:element>
         </xsl:if>
       </xsl:template>
 </studentRequest>
</xsl:template>
```

That means if the input XML form is changed also, I need to produce the same output using XSLT. If the request is small we can write XSLT as above,but if the request is large then is there any alternative solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `<xsl:element>` is always unnecessary **unless** you want to set a calculated element name. `<xsl:element name="student">` is a rater complicated way of saying `<student>`.

Comment: You've made the classic mistake of trying to specify your requirements using a single example, and then telling us later that the example isn't enough to explain the complete requirement. Start again with a better requirements statement. What RULE is it that determines the order of elements in the output?

Comment: @MichaelKay Actually original example is very big,so i have created small example for that.There is no rule here.Actually we are forming a SOAP request as exist in WSIL file.For that we are getting xml file with different forms.But finally we need to form the request according to WSIL.You understand what i said?.Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: If there is no rule that determines the order of the output then there is no way of writing a program to produce the output in the correct order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be sorting the children in some way, but otherwise you just want to copy them.

The way to do these kinds of transformations is always this:

- start with the identity template
- write templates *only* for the nodes you want to modify

Like this

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="student">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="address" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="no" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="address">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="city" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="pin" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="state" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: request is small so no problem with this solution.If the request is large is there any alternative solution

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "problem" and "alternative solution"? What's wrong with the above?

Comment: The code is above is 100% correct .I will agree with that.But if the request contains an XML like which contains  1000 lines writing this type of XSLT will be complex.Above i gave sample XML

Comment: Yes. If the request is complex then the solution tends to be complex. That's how things are in the programming world. This solution is a lot simpler than the XSLT sample in your question, so I really don't see your point.

Comment: OK.Thanks Tomalak ..I am new to XSLT .I have a small question about your code.Can i ask ?

Comment: @PSR - what version of xslt? If you can use 2.0, you can combine xsl:apply-templates and specify order. Like `<xsl:apply-templates select="(address,name,no)"/>`

Comment: Besides, with regard to your question: Element order is (should be) irrelevant in XML. If you have an application that relies on element order that that's a problem. Fixing that application solves the problem. Writing 1000 lines of XSLT that does nothing but re-order elements does not solve the problem.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks, I was about to suggest that as well. :) But it's still a band-aid, IMO.

Comment: For name you write  <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />.But there is no template write for name,What will be the output for this

Comment: @PSR There is a template for `<name>`, it's the first one. It's called the identity template.

Comment: identity template you mean <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83385/discussion-between-psr-and-tomalak).

Comment: @PSR - yes you're right that is the identity template. It will copy all nodes (attribute, element, text, comment, and processing instruction) unchanged. (Unless processing of a node is overridden by a template with a higher priority). So tomalak is correct that `name` will be processed by the identity template. (This is what tomalak is talking about in his bullet points. +1)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just sorting child elements by name. If that's the case, try this...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()"/>                
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No no i am not sorting by name.It is the requirement.But it is not intentional.

Comment: Minimum solution to the original question, so +1, I guess.

Comment: @PSR If you want to output the nodes in a predefined order, then you must either sort them by some property, or call them out one-by-one (or group-by-group) explicitly. If you prefer, you can list the order in which they must appear elsewhere (e.g. in an external document) and use the node's position in the list for sorting. But such explicit list must exist somewhere, if you want to force an order that is neither alphabetical nor numerical.